# How to create a base JSON element without making it an array

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I want to create a JSON object, but the root element should not be an array. I'm using jsonlite::toJSON, but I cannot figure out a way to remove the initial array symbols.

```
FirstLevel=("FirstLevel")
df <- data.frame(FirstLevel)

jsonObj = toJSON(df,pretty = TRUE )
print(jsonObj)
```

I get this

```
[
  {
    "FirstLevel": "FirstLevel"
  }
]
```

but I need to see

```
{
    "FirstLevel": "FirstLevel"
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

ok, found the solution.

https://rdrr.io/cran/jsonlite/man/unbox.html

```
library(jsonlite)

FirstKey=("FirstValue")
df <- data.frame(FirstKey)

jsonObj = toJSON(unbox(df), pretty = TRUE)

print(jsonObj)

#result is below
{
    "FirstKey": "FirstValue"
  }
```